# Browserify & ReactJS issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

Can't get Browserify working with ReactJS. I'm running with watchify, although browserify does same thing:

```
watchify -t reactify app2.js -o ../build/app-brow.js
```

The browser console shows this error in `mywidget.js`:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

**app2.js**

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var MyShow = require('./mywidget').MyWidget;

var myApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
         MyShow: <MyShow />
        <LocalWidget />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent((
  <myApp />
), document.body);
```

**mywidget.js**

```
var MyWidget = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
      Testing "require MyWidget" Captain
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = MyWidget;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>

    <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.14/require.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    This shows, but ReactJS shows errors in browser, console.
    <div id="content"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="build/app-brow.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought it may be missing `/** @jsx React.DOM */` from `mywidget.js` but no work. Also tried adding `var React = require('react');` to .js files, still no go!

Comment: If you want to use the in-browser transformer you need to specify `type="text/jsx"`, though it sounds like that's not your intention here. (In that case, you don't need JSXTransformer.js.)

Comment: A bit OT, have a look at my React + browserify + gulp template: https://gist.github.com/fkling/e34147a800b085a17563

Comment: By the way, RequireJS/AMD is something different, you're using browserify/CommonJS.

Comment: I'm including RequireJS in `index.html` in this tag: `<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.14/require.js">`. Do you mean Browserify turns RequireJS into CommonJS modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mywidget.js you have this:

```
module.exports = MyWidget;
```

When you require a file, you get the value of `module.exports`.

So this line is effectively doing MyWidget.MyWidget, which is undefined.

```
var MyShow = require('./mywidget').MyWidget;
```

You should just remove the `.MyWidget` at the end.

```
var MyShow = require('./mywidget');
```

---

You're also missing `/** @jsx React.DOM */` in the mywidget.js file, which is causing the SyntaxError.

---

Side note: remove JSXTransformer, you don't need it because you're using reactify.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks about removing JSXTransformer script tag, good call!

Answer (score 1):

I have made a basic component of ReactJS using gulp and browserfy.
This blog may help you to make React component [HelloReactComponent](https://masudshrabon.wordpress.com/2015/04/05/reactjs-component-hello-world/)